# How do I reconstruct irregularly spaced lat-lon data (in the form of a matrix) using spherical harmonic fitting?

Tags: machine-learning, python, feature-construction, matrix

[Introductory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) [Links](https://brilliant.org/wiki/spherical-harmonics/) to spherical harmonics give a mildly rigorous introduction to the concept; but very few links describe how to actually use them. I have latitude-longitude data arranged the following way (as an example):

```
00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 12 04 05 06
89 28 25 19 00 12
```

where `00` are simply the points where the data has not been recorded and is thus set to 0. **This is a toy example**; my actual data covers the entire Earth. I would like to know two things:

1. How do I specifically use spherical harmonics to 'fill in' the missing elements in the matrix in Python? Searching online shows utilities like `pyshtools` that seem to be useful, but the actual tutorial for `pyshtools` is unhelpful in my case.
2. What order of spherical harmonic should I select? I was thinking of using a form of k-fold cross-validation to see which order is the best. Are there any rules of thumb about tolerances, orders, number of iterations, I should know so my computational time is reduced as much as possible?